# Cutting out specific text from specific lines in real time

Tags: text-processing, awk, scripting, perl, real-time

So I have a log running in real time and saving to a text file named 'test.txt' also in real time. Now I want to set up a process that constantly polls that text file for changes and cuts out a specific reoccuring bit of data. 
For example the log looks like:

```
Feb  9 11:43:24 dnsmasq[887]: query[A] captive.g.aaplimg.com from 192.168.178.21
Feb  9 11:43:24 dnsmasq[887]: forwarded captive.g.aaplimg.com to 8.8.4.4
Feb  9 11:43:24 dnsmasq[887]: reply captive.g.aaplimg.com is 17.253.55.202
Feb  9 11:43:24 dnsmasq[887]: reply captive.g.aaplimg.com is 17.253.57.211
Feb  9 11:43:54 dnsmasq[887]: query[A] captive.g.aaplimg.com from 192.168.178.21
```

And i want to cut info from only the lines with query[A] so that the output text looks like:

```
11:43 captive.g.aaplimg.com
```

But the problem is that there are different URL's attached to this line of the log, so for example it could look like:

```
Feb  9 11:49:56 dnsmasq[887]: query[A] www.googleapis.com from 192.168.178.21
```

Then I would want the output to be:

```
11:49 www.googleapis.com
```

But it needs to happen in real-time, as the text file/log is updating.

Running on debian buster on pi.

Comment: can you interpose a filter on the log output before it is written to the file?

Answer (score 0):

```
tail -F test.txt | 
   perl -nE 'say "$+{time} $+{url}" if /(?<time>\d{2}:\d{2}):\d{2} dnsmasq\S+: query\S+ (?<url>\S+) from /'
```

The `tail -F` will keep finding ("following") lines that are appended to `test.txt`.

The `perl` filters and extracts the matching lines (and captures the parts of the regex using `(?<named_capture>...)` segments).